# Converting some Excel formula to C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to convert some Excel formulas into C# code, and I'm kind of lost...

I have the following:

```
SUMPRODUCT(1*(RIGHT(A1)={"a","e","i","n","y"}))
```

What exactly does that mean?

Here is what I know:

- `RIGHT(A1)` returns the last character of the text in `A1`.
- `SUMPRODUCT({1,2,3}, {4,5,6})` returns `1*4 + 2*5 + 3*6` (something like a scalar product, right?)

but here is what I don't understand:

If the text is `Claude`, for example...

`RIGHT(A1)={"e","a","b","c","d"}` returns `TRUE`

and

`RIGHT(A1)={"a","b","e","c","d"}` returns `FALSE`

I only changed the index position of the `e` character.

What is happening there?
What I'm not understanding?

Comment: In my Excel 2010 this formula `RIGHT(A1)={"a","b","e","c","d"}` or `RIGHT(A1)={"e", "a","b","c","d"}` is not even accepted! they only thing accepted is when `{}` contains only one string like `"e"` or `"a"`... what excel version are you using ?

Comment: @Yahia: The following formula works just fine in Excel 2010 for me: `=RIGHT(A1)={"a","b","e","c","d"}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically the formula is checking if the last character in cell `A1` is any of the following characters: a, e, i, n, or y.  The `SUMPRODUCT` part is important because it is a hack to check the entire array at once against the last character.  When you strip that part out and just use `RIGHT(A1)={"a","b","e","c","d"}`, Excel actually only looks at the first entry in the array, checks to see if it's a match, and returns immediately.  So when 'e' is in the first position, you get True.

`SUMPRODUCT` allows the checking to be applied across the entire array.  Another way to see this would be to manually type it out into separate cells in a grid fashion like this

```
       A   |       B      |  C  |      D
1 | Claude | =RIGHT(A1,1) | 'a' | =1*(B1=C1)
2 |        | =RIGHT(A1,1) | 'e' | =1*(B2=C2)
3 |        | =RIGHT(A1,1) | 'i' | =1*(B3=C3)
4 |        | =RIGHT(A1,1) | 'n' | =1*(B4=C4)
5 |        | =RIGHT(A1,1) | 'y' | =1*(B5=C5)
6 |        |              |     | =SUM(D1:D5)
```

The bottom right cell would contain a 1 if any of the characters a,e,i,n,y are at the end of the value in A1, or a 0 if not.  I am manually performing the same logic as `SUMPRODUCT` to get to the same result.

So, how this would be accomplished in C#.Net:

```
var checkValue = "Claude";
var letters = {"a", "e", "i", "n", "y"};
var found = 0;

foreach (var theLetter in letters)
    if (checkValue.EndsWith(theLetter))
        found = 1;

return found; // returns same value as Excel function
```

Comment: With some help from LINQ, you could simplify that to `string value = "Claude"; return (new string[] {"a", "e", "i", "n", "y"}).Contains(value[value.Length - 1]) ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want one line based on @CoryLarson's suggestion that will work for any set of letters:

```
Func<string, string[], int> LetterCount = (x, y) => y.Contains(x.Substring(x.Length-1, 1)) ? 1 : 0;
```